# Como chamar um método quando seu parâmetro é um array?

Tags: java

Sou novo em java e estou tendo certas dificuldades em chamar um método, bom, tenho o seguinte:

```
class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        vetorFloat(vetor[x]);
    }
    private float vetorFloat(float[] vetor) {
        //algum código
        return vetor[x];
    }
}
```

O método `vetorFloat` está na mesma classe que o método principal `main`.

Como eu poderia chamar esse método?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assim:

```
float[] floatArray = new float[]{1.0f, 2.2f, 3.4f};
vetorFloat(floatArray);
```

Então o método e classe em **contexto estático** ficaria assim:

```
class main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float[] floatArray = new float[]{1.0f, 2.2f, 3.4f};
        vetorFloat(floatArray );
    }
    private static float vetorFloat(float[] vetor) {
        //algum código
        return vetor[x];
    }
}
```

Só que esse **X** no `return vetor[x];` vai dar problema de compilação. Ele precisa ser resolvido. Pode ser assim:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float[] floatArray = new float[]{1.0f, 2.2f, 3.4f};
        vetorFloat(floatArray );
    }
    private static float vetorFloat(float[] vetor) {
        int x = 0;
        return vetor[x];
    }
}
```

Agora seu método retornará a primeira posição do array passado.

Do jeito que você fez, você está passando um elemento do array, e não o array todo. No meu exemplo, eu declaro um novo array e já o preencho. Logo a variável `floatArray` representa todo o array e se eu fizer `floatArray[0]`, eu estou acessando somente o primeiro elemento do array, que nesse caso é 1.0.

Aquele **"F"** ali depois no número, serve para o Java saber que é um tipo `float`. Quando você preenche um número arbitrado no código, o java não sabe se ele trata como `int`, `float`, `long`... então você especifica após declarar o número. Exemplos:

- `long 0L`
- `float 0.0f`
- `double 0.0d`

Consulte a **[documentação oficial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html)** sobre os tipos primitivos. Pode ajudar bastante.

Comment: Complementando: chamar o método `vetorFloat()` em um contexto estático também dá erro de compilação. Deve-se declarar o método `vetorFloat()` como `static` ou então chamá-lo em contexto de instância (um método não-estático, por exemplo).

Comment: @Piovezan, constatei isso. Utilizei a resposta do Ricardo Giaviti e deu o tal erro na compilação... "_non-static method vetorFloat(float[]) cannot be referenced from a static context_".

Comment: Desculpa pessoal. Não reparei. Editei minha resposta.

Comment: Parei para analisar a situação e percebi uma coisa... Não preciso disso tudo, pois tudo está dentro do método `vetorFloat(float[] vetor)`, quando digo tudo, me refiro a entrada de dados, saída de dados, contas, tratamento de dados e etc, o que quis dizer é algo que apenas diga ao programa: execute esse método. No caso, o método principal `main` seria apenas um método que executa outros métodos, nada além disso.

Answer (score 2):

No seu método `main()` você comete três erros:

1. Usa variáveis não declaradas: `vetor` e `x`
2. Passa um argumento do tipo `float` para um método que tem um vetor de `float`s como parâmetro (`float[]` é um vetor de `float`s)
3. Você chama um método não estático (`vetorFloat()`) a partir de um método estático (`main()`).

Você também faz outras coisas que não são erros porém convém te avisar:

1. De acordo com a convenção utilizada em Java, classes devem começar com uma letra maiúscula.
2. Você não está usando o retorno do método `vetorFloat()` para nada (essa provavelmente você já tinha percebido, mas não pude deixar de citar).

**Consertando**

Isso é apenas uma sugestão minha, ela conserta os erros e o aviso que eu citei acima:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        float[] vetor = {1, 2, 5};
        System.out.println(vetorFloat(vetor));
    }
    private static float vetorFloat(float[] vetor) {
         return vetor[vetor.length-1]; //retorna o último elemento do vetor
    }
}
```

Obs: não esqueça de renomear seu arquivo para `Main.java`