# Usei um array no parâmetro de um método e não sei como executar

Tags: java, array, nullpointerexception

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class Cliente {

    private String nome;
    private String telefone;
    private int codigo;
    private String rua;

    void setRua(String z) {
        rua = z;
    }

    void setTelefone(String t) {
        telefone = t;
    }

    void setCodigo(int n) {
        codigo = n;
    }

    void setNome(String name) {
        this.nome = name;
    }

    int getCodigo(){

        return codigo;
    }

    void cadastroCliente(Cliente cliente, int n) {

        cliente.setCodigo(n);
        cliente.setNome(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Nome: "));
        cliente.setTelefone(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Telefone: "));
        cliente.setRua(JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Rua: "));
    }

    void removerCliente(Cliente cliente, int n) {

        cliente.setNome("");
        cliente.setTelefone("");
        cliente.setRua("");
    }

    void mostrarClientes(Cliente[] cliente) {



            for (int i = 0; i < cliente.length ; i++) {
                if ((cliente[i].getCodigo() != 0 ) && (cliente[i].nome != null)) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, cliente[i].nome);
                }
            }
        }

    }
```

Abaixo o código main.. onde está minha dúvida..

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;<
public class Operacoes {
public static void main(String[] args) {
Cliente teste = new Cliente();

 Cliente cliente[] = new Cliente[30];

cliente[1] = new Cliente();
cliente[2] = new Cliente();
cliente[3] = new Cliente();
cliente[1].cadastroCliente(cliente[1], 1); 
cliente[2].cadastroCliente(cliente[2], 2); 
cliente[3].cadastroCliente(cliente[3], 3); 

teste.mostrarClientes(); // Não sei o que colocar dentro do () 

} 
}
```

Comment: Eu já lhe falei que a estrutura de seu código está toda errada. Você está misturando coisas. 
Me parece estranho que você consiga criar *array*, criar um método que que receba um *array* e não saiba passar o *array* como argumento. Acho que você precisa fazer um cursos de programação antes de começar tentar programar. Seu nome é Igor ou Rodrigo? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/21284/igor-gutemberg

Comment: Relacionado: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/10869/como-chamar-um-m%C3%A9todo-quando-seu-par%C3%A2metro-%C3%A9-um-array

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 3):

Acho que é só isto que você quer.

```
teste.mostrarClientes(cliente);
```

Você pode mudar este método para filtrar o que não tem valores inicializados. Não é o mais correto mas funciona.

```
if (cliente[i] != null && (cliente[i].getCodigo() != 0 ) && (cliente[i].nome != null)) {
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Array/GetValues.java).

Com esta verificação você pulará todos os elementos nulos no *array*, não importando sua posição. O ideal é que não tenha elementos nulos. Só deveria deixar ter por alguma razão muito boa. Mas para fazer o que você deseja seria precisa uma [`ArrayList<E>`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) no lufar do *array*. *Arrays* são muito primitivos e limitados. Eles têm seu uso mas não devem ser usados quando precisa de flexibilidade.

Se ainda for usar o *array*, já que está começando. Ajuda começar popular o *array* pelo índice 0 ao invés do 1 como foi feito originalmente. Mas o melhor é garantir que não gere erro se encontrar uma situação assim, porque elas são possíveis.

Comment: Quando você diz, "Eu já lhe falei que a estrutura de seu código está toda errada." seja mais especifico o Igor é meu amigo de grupo da escola técnica não tivemos aula de array ainda estamos tentando criar este projeto.. Você poderia nos da algumas dicas? O que você falou como resposta retornou este erro.. "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Cliente.mostrarClientes(Cliente.java:53)
 at Operacoes.main(Operacoes.java:19)
Java Result: 1"

Comment: Aí já é outro problema. Aqui não é um fórum, aqui temos apenas perguntas objetivas, focadas para que as respostas sejam assim também. Quando for passar informações de erro, indique qual é a linha porque não temos como saber qual é o número da linha exato. Este erro ocorre porque você está passando um *array* com 30 elementos mas só está inicializando 3 deles. O erro ocorre quando vai acessar o quarto que não está inicializado, lá ele encontra um elemento nulo e quebra. Ou você deve inicializar todos elementos ou trocar por uma lista que permite ir adicionando novos elementos conforme necessita

Comment: Comentários não devem ser usados para postar códigos, então não poste. Você já está fazendo outras perguntas. Veja [tour] e [help]. Quebrei seu galho em uma parte.

Answer (score 2):

É gerada uma `NullPointerException` pelo simples fato da posição 0 do seu array ser nula. O problema começa aqui:

```
cliente[1] = new Cliente(); // Mas e a posição '0' ?!
```

Quando o método `mostrarClientes` for executado, ele começará a percorrer o array da posição **zero** até o tamanho desse array:

```
void mostrarClientes(Cliente[] cliente) {
   for (int i = 0; i < cliente.length ; i++) {
      // 0? NullPointerException...
   }
}
```

Para resolver o problema, basta instanciar o primeiro objeto e inseri-lo na posição zero do array.

```
public class Operacoes {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Cliente teste = new Cliente();

        Cliente cliente[] = new Cliente[30];

        cliente[0] = new Cliente(); //...
        cliente[1] = new Cliente();
        cliente[2] = new Cliente();
        cliente[0].cadastroCliente(cliente[0], 1); //...
        cliente[1].cadastroCliente(cliente[1], 2);
        cliente[2].cadastroCliente(cliente[2], 3);

        teste.mostrarClientes(cliente); // E aqui, você passa o array de 'Cliente'
    }
}
```

<sup>**OBS:** Dê nomes autoexplicativos para as suas variáveis/atributos/classes/métodos/whatever, isso ajudará tanto você quanto quem for te ajudar.</sup>